# How to upload image to existing MySql database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I'm creating an android application and i'm trying to store profile image for user. When user register, he is recorded in table, and i have inserted one more field there `image` where i will store images for him. But i guess that i will need to use PUT request method when sending a query. I'm uploading that image based on user id and authenticate key-api which every user gets when registered. This is what i have done so far:

```
public function uploadImage($user_id, $image, $status) {
    $path = "uploads/$user_id.png";
    $actualpath = "http://localhost:8081/timster/uploads/$path";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET image = $actualpath, status = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sii", $image, $status, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_affected_rows > 0;
}
```

Here i'm really stuck i don't know what should i do next. 
And this is how i'm sending a query for updating `users` table and uploading image.

```
$app->put('/image/:id', 'authenticate', function($user_id) use ($app) {

    // check for required params
    verifyRequiredParams(array('image', 'status'));

    global $user_id;
    $image = $app->request->put('image');
    $status = $app->request->put('status');

    $db = new DbHandler();
    $response = array();

    $result = $db->uploadImage($user_id, $image, $status);
    if ($result) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Image uploaded successfully";
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Image failed to upload";
    }
    echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

I didn't run this for checking if it is working, but i'm sure that i need something more to add in function `uploadImage()`.

So, for example, this is how will my url look when sending a PUT request.
`http://localhost:8081/timster/v1/image/2`. The last number is the id of a user where i want to upload a new image.

Comment: is your image being uploaded to the folder uploads ? , as i don't see any file upload code in your code.

Comment: It should be. Should i done some changes in php code?

Comment: Side note: should a user be able upload for other users? If not Id skip the user id in the URL and just use the user id in the token instead

Comment: When the user login, i'm storing datas from mysql like id, name, email to the SqLite and retrieving those datas later and with the id retrieved from SqLite i'm sending a PUT request.